# what is Fingersgesture event on android?

Tags: android, multi-touch

My app on android 13 when I press three keys at once logcat displays a fingers gesture event

On android 8 there is no such event on three touch event

What is it?

How is it created by my app?

I have disabled anything touch related gestures on the android os settings without effect

If i press seperatelythe keys multitouch works but when i press three keys at once i get this erroneous gesture event that ccompletely ruins the multitouch capability of my app.

any help appreciated